# How Write Array Data more than one to txt file android

Tags: java, android

based on the below code I only can save 1 data, but the array data is more than 1. how to save data to txt file more than 1 data.

```
File file = new File(Visualization.this.getFilesDir(), "text");
                                    if (!file.exists()) {
                                        file.mkdir();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        File gpxfile = new File(file, "sample.txt");
                                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                                        writer.append(rightDataDict.toString());
                                        writer.flush();
                                        writer.close();
    //                                    Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Saved your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rightDataDict is string you can use this codes. your codes might be like this. else rightDataDict, edit the loop according to it's format

```
File file = new File(Visualization.this.getFilesDir(), "text");
                                    if (!file.exists()) {
                                        file.mkdir();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        File gpxfile = new File(file, "sample.txt");
                                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                                        for(String i: rightDataDict){
                                            writer.append(i);
                                        }
                                        writer.flush();
                                        writer.close();
    //                                    Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Saved your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```